timing your dead hang
Doing a "dead hang" - hanging from a pullup bar by your hands - is supposed to be very beneficial; it strengthens your grip, decompresses your spine, and alleviates the symptoms of shoulder impingement, among other things.
So it's good to work up to doing it as long as you can.   But what's an easy way to measure your hang time, if you don't have a stopwatch or wall-clock with a second hand handy ?  For example, if you're running on an outdoor trail with various exercise stations along it.

Stopwatches are not really that expensive are they?

You can think of your body, hanging from the pullup bar, as a pendulum.   Pendulums have the characteristic that their period, T, the time it takes to swing back and forth one time, depends upon ONLY the length, L, of the pendulum.  There is a slight variation, but T varies by less than 1%, for all but very large swings.
Thus, as long as your height and arm length and body-weight distribution remain the same, T is an immutable constant for you, and thus you can accurately measure your hang time without a clock of any sort.   You're not measuring minutes or seconds, but rather this arbitrary constant T, but it doesn't matter, all you're trying to do is to measure and track improvement.
As an aside, T is given by the equation:
T = 2 * PI * sqrt (L/g)

... where g is the acceleration due to gravity, 32 ft/sec^2.   So if you can measure T accurately with a clock (by measuring the number of seconds it takes to do however many swings you can manage), you can compute L, or the location of your body's center of gravity (of course, it's your body with both arms extended maximally).
Also, swinging can increase the risk of injury as joints are extended to hyper-extended and bearing your body weight, and then there’s the increase in force due to the momentum of your body swinging to and fro. But if you make the swings very gentle (your feet moving perhaps 6" to and fro from hanging motionless), this shouldn't be much of a factor.

This seems inferior to counting the seconds in your head.

The period of the pendulum is constant (for any given person).   Counting seconds is a lot less accurate.

You are also assuming that the swing of the pendulum remains constant. This may be true for a mechanical construct, but not a human, Plus, if you are swinging back and forth, it's not a dead hang.

Very gentle swing, not putting appreciably more stress on shoulder joints that dead hang.

I guess human could alter the period of the swing a little, the way you a child would on a swingset to go higher and higher.   But if you try to remind still, I think it'd be pretty constant.
